# Extra fields with add record in jtable

Tags: jquery, jtable

I have a jtable which display the information of firstname, lastname, email.

[image]

Now once I click on "Add new record", I need some more extra fields like roles(in drop down), address etc along with the firstname,lastname and username and email. Right now the default fields which I have defined within fields in jquery getting displayed.

[image]

Can I know how can I add new fields only for "New record".

Code:

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
  var RowNumber = 0;         
    $('#PersonTableContainer').jtable({
        title: 'All Users',
        paging: true, //Enables paging
        pageSize: 10, //Actually this is not needed since default value is 10.
        sorting: true, //Enables sorting
        defaultSorting: 'firstName ASC',
        actions: {
            listAction: '/training/user/getuser',
            createAction: '/training/user/create',
            updateAction: '/GettingStarted/UpdatePerson',
            deleteAction: '/GettingStarted/DeletePerson'
        },
        fields: {

           /*  id: {
                key: true,
                list: false
            },  */
            firstName: {
                title: 'First Name',
                width: '40%'
            } ,
            lastName: {
                title: 'Last Name',
                width: '20%'
            },
             username: {
                title: 'User Name',
                width: '30%',
                create: false,
                edit: false
            },  
            email: {
                title: 'Email',
                width: '20%'
            }  
        }
    });
    $('#PersonTableContainer').jtable('load');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. we have to mention field which i want in below way to display it in only during create functionality

```
        Roles: {
                title: 'Roles',
                 list: false,
                create: true,
                edit: false
            }
```